# expected value of random variable defined in terms of uniformly distributed variables

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

> For each $1\leq i\leq n, $ let $U_i$ be a random variable with the $U(0,1)$ distribution, and assume the $U_i$'s are independent. Define $N = \min\{ n : (\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \geq k)\}, k\in\mathbb{R}^+.$ What is the expected value of $N$? If $k\to \infty,$ what would the expected value approximately be?

I know the definition of expected value for continuous variables: $E[g(X)] := \int_{\mathrm{Range}(X)} g(x)f(x)dx.$ Here I think it makes sense to consider $N$ to be the minimum possible sum of the $U_i$'s that exceeds $k$. So it seems difficult to find a concrete formula for $N,$ but this might help find the expected value. Also, $N$ can vary quite a bit; many of the $U_i$'s may be $0.$ Maybe the range $(0,1)$ has some significance; changing it may result in a different answer, or maybe there is some easy generalization to the case where each $U_i\sim U(a,b)$?

Comment: Do you mean that $N$ is the least $n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \ge k$? What you wrote is "$N$ is the minimum, over all $n$, of the expression $\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \ge k$", which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MishaLavrov sorry. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

(Well, at first, I didn't want to send this reply. But with the fear that no one would give you another answer, I'll give your question a start).

If you have learned about Markov chain, $N$ is just a stopping time.
But I think you still did not touch anything related to that subject.
So in this case, you may notice that $S_n= \sum_{i=1}^n U_i$ is strictly increasing wrt to $n$. 
Hence, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, we have:

- $\mathbb{P}( N > n ) =  \mathbb{P}( S_n < k )=\mathbb{P}\left( \frac{S_n-\mathbb{E}(S_n)}{\sqrt{n}} < \frac{k-n/2}{\sqrt{n}} \right) =(*)$
- and, $\mathbb{E}(N)= \sum_{n \ge 0}\mathbb{P}( N > n )$

The term $(*)$ can be controlled by some approximations on the tail of a normal variable. But this is somehow messy so I don't go any further.

Comment: how did you get a normal distribution? And isn't $n$ at least $1$ because otherwise the empty sum would be zero, which is not greater than or equal to any positive $k$? And isn't $\mathbb{E}(N) = \sum_{n\geq 0} n\cdot \mathbb{P}(N = n)$? How is this equivalent to your definition?

Comment: Hm. So I guess my answer is not suitable for you. You can wait for a neater answer from others, while I show you why I have the second equality $$ \sum_{n\ge 0} \mathbb{P}(N>n)= \sum_{ n \ge 0, k \ge n+1} \mathbb{P}(N=k) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \sum_{0 \le n \le k-1}  \mathbb{P}(N=k)  = \sum_{k \ge 1}  k\mathbb{P}(N=k)$$